# Сохранить елементы TreeView в XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, silverlight

Есть заполненный TreeView (инфой о папках и файлах на диске). Нужно сохранить эту инфу в XML. Под WindowsForm решений куча, под WPF - не нашел ниодного толком рабочего. Подскажите, если знаете как это сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Решение есть: [сериализация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx). (Вот ещё [пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/et91as27.aspx).) Для вашего случая -- [XML-сериализация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Разумеется, сохранять надо не `TreeView` (это ведь графический объект!), а данные модели.

(ЗЫ: Если вы пользуетесь MVVM, вам будет проще.)